# Dragging effect from keyboard

Tags: microsoft-excel

Is there a way to create 'dragging' effect from keyboard only, not using the mouse. This could be useful for Excel, Word etc.

For example, the fill handles in Excel could use this feature.

Comment: [Using the Fill Handle from the Keyboard](http://excel.tips.net/T003922_Using_the_Fill_Handle_from_the_Keyboard.html)

Comment: Close, but I wish to mimic the action of the mouse

Comment: What version of Windows are you using?

Comment: Windows 7 (32-bit) and MS Office 2013 (32-bit)

Answer (score 1):

Use the Mouse Keys under Accessibility Options / Ease of Access Center in the Windows Control Panel.

For Windows 7:
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/use-mouse-keys-to-move-the-mouse-pointer

Press <kbd>Numpad 0</kbd> to start drag.  Press <kbd>Numpad .</kbd> to end drag.